# Who is responsible for updates to the JSON spec?

Tags: json, standards, specifications

I am tired of working around the fact that JSON does not support binary data.

While there are workarounds, it would be nicer for me to get the specification updated to support binary data properly.

Who is responsible for updates to the JSON specification?

If you have ideas/dreams/whishes how to improve JSON, then please let me know. Just create a issue here [Let's fix JSON (github)](https://github.com/guettli/lets-fix-json)

Comment: IETF, https://www.ietf.org/

Comment: see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON

Comment: @YakovL there are several ways to walk around the fundamental issue. One walk around is to use a completely different format like BSON. The list is long. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data-serialization_formats But the switch to a different format is not simple. I lot of code depends on JSON. That's why I think a transition does make more sense, than a completely different format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) on JSON, it has been standardized in [ECMA-404](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-404%201st%20edition%20October%202013.pdf), [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) *and* [ISO/IEC 21778:2017](http://www.iso.org/cms/render/live/en/sites/isoorg/contents/data/standard/07/16/71616.html). Realistically speaking, JSON is now such an established standard that it is impossible to change without breaking many services relying on the current JSON format. I.e. *it is not going to happen*.

The most common way to get around this is to encode the binary data as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and agree that's how it's done in the application layer.

Another answer could be to use a different protocol - Wikipedia has a nice [Comparison of data serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data-serialization_formats).

(And while we're picking on JSON, may I add the lack of dates as one of my personal itches.)

Comment: Yes, I miss a date data type very much.

Comment: You say "it is not going to happen.". I think sooner or later there will be some kind of JSON2. Up to now I don't see an alternative which gains traction.

Answer (score 1):

ECMA International TC39.
You can follow and contribute to specs here:
https://github.com/tc39